# How can I make stickyHeader match LazyRow height?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple `LazyRow` with sticky headers. I would like my sticky headers to match the `LazyRow` height. How can it be achieved?

My code is a bit more complicated, but this code sample is enough to illustrate my problem:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun TestPreview() {
    LazyRow {
        stickyHeader {
            Text("Header", modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Cyan))
        }
        items(10) {
            Text("Hello World", modifier = Modifier
                .size(200.dp)
                .background(Color.Blue))
        }
    }
}
```

My ultimate goal is to have Header vertically centered with it's background matching the height of the `LazyRow`.

[image: Preview]

I have tried `Modifier.fillMaxHeight()` with this result:

[image: Preview 2]

Comment: did you try `Modifier.fillMaxHeight()`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. I've update my question & added a new screenshot.

Comment: Well yeah you'd need to limit the height of the `LazyRow` itself

Comment: Or, since you already have `size(200.dp)` on the content, why not just `size(height=200.dp)` on the header?

Comment: I oversimplified my example, `size(200.dp)` is only there to visualize the problem. I don't know the size of my `LazyRow` upfront.

Comment: if all else fails, there's always an `onGloballyPositioned` listener on the content that updates a `State<Dp>` for the header. Ugly, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.height(Intrinsic.Min)` for the `LazyRow` and can use `.fillMaxWidth()` for the `Header`. This will limit the height of `LazyRow` to the minimum and hence the header will achieve it's parent height.

Comment: I cannot do that: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Asking for intrinsic measurements of SubcomposeLayout layouts is not supported. This includes components that are built on top of SubcomposeLayout, such as lazy lists, BoxWithConstraints, TabRow, etc.

Comment: That sounds like a bug to me. `LazyRow` only scales horizontally, so having an intrinsic on the height should be fine. Not that that helps you right now, of course.

Comment: @Jorn I think this is working like this: In `Row` or `Column` all the composable composes at once and hence the measurements can be taken easily. But in case of `Lazy` composable there might be some changes in `height` or `width` across the complete list and they are also created `lazily` so its difficult to sure the measurements of each item.

Comment: @Ziem So its better to use just `Row` instead of `LazyRow` if you can fewer items in the list with `.horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())` method for the `Modifier` of `Row` but you have to achieve the `stickHeader` functionality by using some other way.